# How query data and print entire row from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

I am trying to create a simple lambda function that is initiated by an IOT dash button. What it will do is take the `serialNumber` from the button and then query it. Once it finds the row it will take all the information pertaining to it and print it.

My code is --->

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print 'Init 1Push_Care_DATAprint'
    Device_ID_var = event['serialNumber']
    print event

    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('Device_ID').eq('Device_ID_var')
    )
    items = response['Items']
    print(items)
```

It simply isn't working, can someone help me with this? I also need to know where the information is printed.

Comment: This code as is will not run. `table` is not defined.

Comment: This might help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't print from a lambda function - i.e. to an actual printer, but the output should be in your cloudwatch logs which you access from the monitoring page for  the lambda function in the aws console.